# Soundplay node ERROR

Tags: audio, error-handling, nodes, subscription, ros

When I run this code and push the bumper of the turtlebot it displays this message:

> [ WARN] [1430824597.483791184]: Sound command issued, but no node is subscribed to the topic. Perhaps you forgot to run soundplay_node.py.

Eventhough I'm pretty sure I've subscribed to the soundplay node

```cpp
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "kobuki_msgs/BumperEvent.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include "kobuki_msgs/WheelDropEvent.h"
#include "sstream"
#include <sound_play/sound_play.h>

using namespace std;
//sound_play::SoundClient sc ;
//sound_play::SoundClient soundClient;
void soundPlaynode(int n);

void bumperCallback(const kobuki_msgs::BumperEvent &bmsg) {
  int state=bmsg.state;
  int side=bmsg.bumper;

  if (side==0 && state==1) {
    cout << "I am rotating to Right" << endl;
    //soundClient.say("I am rotating to Right");
    //soundPlaynode(0);
    geometry_msgs::Twist vel_msg;

    double secs =ros::Time::now().toSec();
    while(secs < 2.5) {
      vel_msg.angular.x = 0;
      vel_msg.angular.y = 0;
      vel_msg.angular.z =-0.6;
    }
    while(secs < 5) {
      vel_msg.linear.x =0.4;
      vel_msg.linear.y =0;
      vel_msg.linear.z =0;
    }
  }
  else if (side==1 && state==1) {
    cout << "Front side is pressed" << endl;
    soundPlaynode(1);
    geometry_msgs::Twist vel_msg;

    double secs =ros::Time::now().toSec();
    while(secs < 3.14) {
      vel_msg.angular.x = 0;
      vel_msg.angular.y = 0;
      vel_msg.angular.z =(double)1;
    }
    secs = 0 ;
    while(secs < 20) {
      vel_msg.linear.x =1.0;
      vel_msg.linear.y =0;
      vel_msg.linear.z =0;
    }
  }
  else if (side==2 && state==1) {
    cout << "I am rotating to Left" << endl;
    //soundClient.say("I am rotating to Left");
    soundPlaynode(2);
    geometry_msgs::Twist vel_msg;
    double secs =ros::Time::now().toSec();
    while(secs < 2.5) {
      vel_msg.angular.x = 0;
      vel_msg.angular.y = 0;
      vel_msg.angular.z =0.6;
    }
    while(secs < 5) {
      vel_msg.linear.x =0.4;
      vel_msg.linear.y =0;
      vel_msg.linear.z =0;
    }
  }
}

int counter = 0 ;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "collision_reaction_node");
  ros::NodeHandle node;
  sound_play::SoundClient sc;
  sc.say("Hello world!");
  // soundPlaynode(1);
  ros::Subscriber bumperSubscriber = node.subscribe("/mobile_base/events/bumper", 100, bumperCallback);
  ros::Publisher velocity_publisher = node.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist> ("/turtle1/cmd_vel", 1000);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
  // ros::Publisher voicePlayerPublisher = node.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/voice_player/message_to_play", 10);
  // ros::Publisher voicePlayerPublisher = node.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/robotsound", 10);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}

void soundPlaynode(int n) {
  sound_play::SoundClient soundClient;
  if(n == 0)
  soundClient.say("I am rotating to the right");
  else if(n == 1) {
    soundClient.say("I am rotating 180 degrees");
  }
  else if(n == 2)
    soundClient.say("I am rotating to the left");
  }
}
```